# How to select data.table columns whose name is variable

Tags: r, data.table

I want to subset a data.table by selecting specific columns. However, I don't want to specify all column names, I want to select them via a variable.

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = 11:20, z = 1:10)
col <- "x"
```

Now, I want to do something like this:

```r
dt2 <- dt[, c(col, "y")]
```

This is supposed to be the same as

```r
dt[, c("x", "y")]
```

However, dt2 is a character vector containing the values `"x"` and `"y"`

I have also tried subsetting the data.table using a list

```r
dt2 <- dt[, .(get(col), y)]
```

This does work, but it does not keep the column name and I need to rename that column (and possibly multiple columns if I select more columns via a variable). Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in the `, with = FALSE`

```
dt <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = 11:20, z = 1:10)
col <- "x"
dt[, c(col, "y"), with=FALSE]
```